# iPad displays a notification asking me to unlock it to use USB accessories, while nothing was plugged in

Tags: ipad, usb, security, bluetooth, hacking

My iPad just displayed a notification “unlock iPad to use USB accessories” or something. Nothing was plugged in.

Other details: Bluetooth was on and an Apple Pencil was connected. There was a keyboard attached via the Smart Connector (3 metallic dots on the back of the iPad). The only thing I could think of that was remotely related was that I took the keyboard off briefly then put it back on.

Was I getting hacked via some high-tech bluetooth exploit that disguises itself as a USB accessory? (I know it sounds crazy but it just reminds me of the Windows thing a while ago where there were USB sticks that made the system believe they were keyboards so that they could execute code as if you had typed it in)

Comment: Is there dust in the port maybe? Or did you have something plugged in before and the message was just late (or stuck)?

Comment: PS: Hacking an USB device to represent itself as a keyboard towards a computer is something completely different than hacking BT to act as an USB accessory.

Comment: Has hacking BT to act as USB been done?

Comment: Given enough effort, motivation and a few iOS bugs it might be possible, sure. But unless you are a high-profile person (and therefore a valuable target for organized crime or secret services) I would look for more mundane explanations first.

Comment: Not a high profile person. It’s just really weird - never seen this happen before. The port is clean it hasn’t been plugged in to charge for days. I’m trying to find out how the Smart Connector is wired, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: which version of iPadOS? which generation of Apple Pencil? actually, which kind of iPad?